# How do I get the URL fragment (hash) from a Facebook app URL passed to the app's canvas?

Tags: facebook, url, canvas, hash, fragment

I'm coding a "one page" app inside facebook (using the canvas app approach). While the user moves inside the app I'm changing the location like: apps.facebook.com/my-app#current_location and loading stuff via AJAX.

Unfortunetely, when someone loads http://apps.facebook.com/my-app#current_location in their browser, the canvas app doesn't see the url fragment #currrent_page.

How can I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot answer properly your question, (and as I think it's kind of old already) the info below should help other people understand better these # (hash) things. **They are called *URL Fragments*.**

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

> Any URL that contains a # character is a fragment URL. The portion of
>   the URL to the left of the # identifies a resource that can be
>   downloaded by a browser and the portion on the right, known as the
>   fragment identifier, specifies a location within the resource:
>
> [image: layout of a url fragment]
>
> ## Fragments Are not Sent in HTTP Request Messages
>
> If you try using fragment URLs in an HTTP sniffer like HttpWatch,
>   you’ll never see the fragment IDs in the requested URL or Referer
>   header. The reason is that the fragment identifier is only used by the
>   browser – it doesn’t affect which resource is returned from the
>   server.Here’s a screen shot of HttpWatch showing the traffic generated
>   by refreshing a fragment URL:
>
> [image: HttpWatch Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The URL fragment is only read on the client-side (users' browsers), so Facebook won't and can't sent that on the POST request it makes to your server.

What you can do is catch all URLs with the same route, regardless of the server-side language of your choice, encode them somehow, and send them to the client to be read by client-side Javascript which would then be responsible for navigating.

Example: the user loads http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/current_location (notice the **/** instead of the **#**). You serve your single page, where you'll have something like (ERB):

`<script>MyApp.navigate("<%= request.path %>");</script>`

Your navigate function could do the following:

```
function navigate(path) {
    window.location.href = "#" + path;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in my app I won't be able to set the url to  http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/current_location via JS while the user is browsing the app without refreshing the browser. I can only set it to http://apps.facebook.com/my-app#current_location and if someone copy's that URL to send it to a friend... no luck...

Comment: I see no way around that. Maybe make use of some UI commonplaces like «permalink», or «email to friend», or «bookmark».

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the Hash urls are nice to use for navigation within your site, however, not so good when sharing the url.  The solution is to create canonical URLs for each of your objects.

So, when someone can access specific information like http://yoursite.com/#artists/styx, you also have a way for your server to serve content from http://yoursite.com/artists/styx.  This way someone can share http://apps.facebook.com/yoursiteapp/artists/styx and then get to the correct content within your site.